# Installing USB drivers before plugging in the device

Tags: usb, installation, driver

We have a device that requires we install drivers before it's plugged in, otherwise we need to remove the drivers that Windows 8 and 10 automatically download.

How do we make a USB driver installer that can install correctly whether it's plugged in first or not?

Comment: In Windows you can **disable** drivers without uninstalling/removing them, see http://www.thewindowsclub.com/uninstall-disable-roll-back-update-drivers-windows To write own drivers you need the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) to access kernel functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn305112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Move to Linux...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, my simple driver for usbser.sys with just an INF file and a CAT file will automatically take precedence over Microsoft's usbser.inf that they supply in Windows 10.  But if that doesn't happen for your particular driver/device, you might look into using [DevCon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), an open source utility from Microsoft that can be used to list devices and update their drivers.  I have never used DevCon in an installer, but I think I have noticed other installers that use it.  There is an [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io) package for DevCon.

Answer (score 0):

We use DPinst which is a Driver Package installer program that Microsoft supply. It is quite flexible & straightforward to use & can give you a pretty standard wizard UI.